# How to change the data type in a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, type-conversion

In MySQL is there a way to change the data type of a field, other than the original data type, without having an intermediate table involvement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [12.10. Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

> The `CAST()` function takes an expression of any type and produces a
>   result value of a specified type, similar to `CONVERT()`.
>
> `CAST(expr AS type)`
>
> and
>
> `CONVERT(expr,type)`, `CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)`

Answer (score 4):

CAST(expr AS type) is limited to convert to the following types:

- BINARY
- CHAR
- DATE
- DATETIME
- SIGNED
- TIME
- UNSIGNED

If you need to convert to something else,, e.g., a boolean (BIT (1)), the following will work. Define a function with the return type you need and calculate your value inside the function body.

If you call this function from the definition of a view column, the type of the column will be the return type of your function.

Comment: As someone with years of Microsoft SQL-Server experience, coming to MySQL for the first time: this limitation is infuriating.